# ALTER DATABASE - Cannot process request. Not enough resources to process request.

Tags: azure-synapse

I am working to automate some of my performance tests on Azure SQL Data Warehouse.  I had been scaling up/down the databases using the Azure portal.  I read in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204042.aspx that it is possible to use T-SQL to accomplish this via

ALTER DATABASE  ...

In my first attempt using T-SQL, the attempt failed:

```
RunScript:INFO:  Mon Feb  6 20:11:06 UTC 2017 : Connecting to host      "logicalserver.database.windows.net" database "master" as "myuser"
RunScript:INFO: stdout from sqlcmd will follow...
ALTER DATABASE my_db MODIFY ( SERVICE_OBJECTIVE =  'DW1000' ) ;

Msg 49918, Level 16, State 1, Server logicalserver, Line 1
Cannot process request. Not enough resources to process request. Please retry you request later.
RunScript:INFO:  Mon Feb  6 20:11:17 UTC 2017 : Return Code = "1" from host "logicalserver.database.windows.net" database "master" as "myuser"
RunScript:INFO: stdout from sqlcmd has ended ^.
```

I immediately went to the Azure portal, requested a scale, and it worked (taking 10 minutes to complete).

Is there any explanation?

Comment: The scale down operation did work on the first attempt.

Comment: The second attempt at a T-SQL scale up operation did work.